# Retrieving list item in application of conditionals

Tags: python-3.x

i have a list with module names with certain keywords. I am trying to find corresponding list item containing those keywords. After finding it, I want to use the matched list item for further operations. Also if the corresponding keyword is not found in any of the list items, i would like to also print message. I have tried following code, but obviously i cannot print message if the keyword is not found, because it will print the msg everytime loop is completed. Summarised part of my code looks like this, for example:

```
list1 = ["M_DASH-COWL_ECAS_RHD_V1.rad","M_DASH-COWL_ECAS_LHD_V1.rad", "M_B-PILLAR_ECAS_5DR_V1.rad","M_ROOF_PAN_ECAS_4DR_V1.rad"]

for p in list1:
    if "pan" in p.lower() and "4dr" in p.lower():
        # do operations on p
        #break the loop
        break
print("list doesnt have corresponding module file name.")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [else](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements):

```
for p in list1:
    if "pan" in p.lower() and "4dr" in p.lower():
        # do operations on p
        #break the loop
        break
else:
    print("list doesnt have corresponding module file name.")
```

Comment: But, i would like to have the error message after all list items are exhausted. if first item is not matched, it will go to else directly. i want all items to be checked.

Comment: @makino Sure, I changed the indentation to match your request. `else` will trigger only if  `break` doesn't.